# Using next alongside an express server (in dev)

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

I have an existing express server which I use as my 'back-end'.
I'm just moving my front-end to nextJS, and would like to proxy my nextJS requests through to the port my back-end is running on. Can I do this?

The main issue I have is that I can't use authentication cookies as the back end serves the OAuth flow (on port 5000) but the front end is hosted on port 3000. Ideally, I'd be able to push everything through port 3000, and have next redirect quietly in the background, which would allow me to use the session cookies as normal.

Comment: What is the question? :]

Comment: I want to set up the next app with my express server so that the browser can interact with either via the same port

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to implement it:

1. Front end server will proxy the path of api to the api backend using.

   For example http://localhost:3000/api/ will be proxied to the back-end service.
   https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware
2. Using a reverse proxy in front of both services, such as nginx.

   This approach has several benefits:

   1. Serve static assets from nginx (which it does really well) that will reduce requests from your front end service.
   2. Cache requests without changes in your services.
   3. Load balancing multiple instances of your api / front node services -advance.

   https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/